# How to make Table of Contents manually

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I'm trying to make table of contents manually, I mean I set the page of each of sections one by one. Here's my target:
[image]
and I'm using `book` class here.

Here's the code that I found

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\bfseries Contents\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0ex}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{. }
\newlength\tocindent
\settowidth\tocindent{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum9\cftchapaftersnum}
\edef\cftchapnumwidth{\the\tocindent}
\edef\cftsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent2.3em
\edef\cftsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent3.2em
\edef\cftsubsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\newcommand\tocmainmatter
{\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{white}}%
}
\xapptocmd\mainmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocmainmatter}}{}{}


\newif\ifschaptertoc
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]%
{{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
}%
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
\ifschaptertoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\schaptertoctrue

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\blindtext

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\blindtext

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\chapter*{ABBREVIATIONS}
\Blindtext

\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\Blindtext

\mainmatter

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\blindtext

\section{General Background}
\blindtext

\section{Objective}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 2}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 3}
\blindtext

\section{Scheme}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you put your minimal LaTeX code that reproduce your problem? It seems to me that the image is built with Word of Microsoft Office.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes it is

Comment: would you please help me out of this problem?

Comment: There is an excellent answer of Fran. If you problem is solved, you check green mark to the @Fran' answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems a XY problem. I cannot figure why do you want to do this (Y) and maybe knowing the true problem (X)) we can suggest better solution. Nonetheless, the trick for "Y" is simple: just open the auxiliary `.toc` file created after the compilation of the code you showed, then, just "copy & paste & modify as you want" in substitution of the `\tableofcontents`, or in a empty .tex document, and *voilá*, a manual TOC:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}
\contentsline {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** 10-30-2023

The procedure is still just copy from the  `.toc` file the  `\contentsline`  and modify the arguments accordingly  to your needs, but  now the kernel command need four arguments, not three. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}{}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}{}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}{}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}{}%
\end{document}
```

If you are curious about the reasons because this not longer works:

```
 \contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
```

but this, that add nothing, will work:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}{}%
```

The reason is that the kernel definition of this command has been [changed recently](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/633) because `hyperref` redefines the command to four arguments, so if you used hyperref, your ToC will ended with entries like that:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{i}{chapter*.1}%
```

But if you then removed hyperref from the preamble, you ended with this `\contentsline` with 4 arguments, but the original kernel definition expected only three, causing issues.

The new kernel definition solve problems loading/unloading `hyperref` but causing an error with old code. One more reason to not to make the ToC from the scratch.

Comment: Very good. You have created a very simple code.

Comment: @Sebastiano. But really I have not created anything! If you editor does not hide/remove the auxiliary files, compile the MWE of the question and  open the created `.toc` file by `pdflatex`. You can check that is nearly the same code. My "brilliant idea" here was only include it in a compilable document and change something.

Comment: For my opinion is very good and.....+1.

Comment: Helpful when including several papers as pdf's.

Comment: @Fran, can you please tell whether is it possible to define custom colors only for chapters? One of the possible ways is it use \textcolor{blue}{Colored text}. However this makes the code verbose. So is there a way to set a global color for all the entries of the chapter?

Comment: @Aim Do you know what Latex commands are mainly macros? If not, search about `\newcommand`.  It exists  just to simplify the code.

Comment: What do you mean with this "just open the auxiliary .toc file created after the compilation of the code you showed"?

Comment: How can this be done in Overleaf?

Comment: @Verónica Just modify my example (annoying for a  long toc, I know) or go to the "Logs and output files" icon →  "Other logs and files"   → "toc file"

Comment: @Fran what's that for? I found a file. Why does your code marks errors when I run it on Overleaf?

Comment: @Verónica My code works without errors in Overleaf. You are doing something wrong. Just paste it **as is** (**all** the code)  in an  **empty** document and compile it.

Comment: @Fran The thing is that I have other things in my document. So I can't paste it in an empty document. I took from `\noindent` to the last `\contentsline`, and marked 14 errors. Most of them say: \contentsline has an extra } and runaway argument?

Comment: @Verónica In a copy of your document you must reduce the text and code progressively, until the problem disappear. Then undo last deletion and continue removing smaller parts, until is not possible any  reduction without removing also the error. Now the source of the error should be evident. Be careful  when removing to not introduce additional errors (e.g. do not remove packages if still are used, do not leave a   `\begin{foo}` without `\end{foo}`, etc.

Comment: @Fran Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear down voter. Can you explain what is wrong with the accepted answer?

Comment: While not the downvoter, with modern latex, this simply doesn't work.  It appears using an even number of contentsline entries, half of them will be misformatted, with their first argument printed; using an odd number, it will fail with "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item".

Comment: @ConstantineEvans. This worked when answered , five years ago. Today the procedure is still the same (just copy from the  `.toc`   `\contentsline ` and modify the arguments accordingly  to your needs)  but  the kernel command definition has been changed recently and now need a 4th argument.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Veronica I had the same trouble but I solve it writing the commands like this:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{section.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}State of Science and Technology}{3}{section.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1}Mathematical Model of Flexible Robotic Manipulators}{1}{subsection.2.1}
```