# Single Page table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to make a single page table of contents in this style

```
Introduction ..................................... 1
Next Point ....................................... 2
```

Without generating it from a LaTex-Document? I printed a bundle of scripts for programming classes that are not written in latex but i want to have a clean table of contents with a custom of the pages.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lines of the table of contents are generated using `\contentsline`.
You can also call this macro yourself to create a toc manually.
The general syntax is

```
\contentsline{<chapter/section/subsection/subsubsection>}{<title>}{<page>}
```

and if you want these entries to be numbered you should insert `\numberline{<section number>}` at the start of the second argument.
To use the `chapter` level heading you need to use a document class that supports it (like `book` or `report`).

Here is an example. 
I'm numbering only half of the sections to illustrate how this works and what the result looks like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Table of contents}

\contentsline{section}{Introduction}{1}
\contentsline{subsection}{First subsection}{1}
\contentsline{subsection}{Second subsection}{3}
\contentsline{subsection}{Third subsection}{3}

\contentsline{section}{\numberline{2}First real section}{5}
\contentsline{subsection}{\numberline{2.1}First subsection}{5}
\contentsline{subsection}{\numberline{2.2}Second subsection}{6}
\contentsline{subsection}{\numberline{2.3}Third subsection}{8}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Here is a version that takes care of the section numbers automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\tocsection[2]{%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \contentsline{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\tocsubsection[2]{%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \contentsline{subsection}{\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Table of contents}

\tocsection{Introduction}{1}
\tocsubsection{First subsection}{1}
\tocsubsection{Second subsection}{3}
\tocsubsection{Third subsection}{3}
\tocsection{First real chapter}{5}
\tocsubsection{First subsection}{5}
\tocsubsection{Second subsection}{6}
\tocsubsection{Third subsection}{8}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

In a document class with actual chapters, `\tocchapter` could be implemented in the same way.

---

If you need to customise the appearance of the toc you can use either [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) or [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

For instance, if you don't want the to be in boldface and you want them to come with (the dots), you could add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

If you only use section level headings, this would match the appearance described in your question.

---

Remark: `\contentsline` takes an additional argument if `hyperref` is loaded (the target for the hyperlink). 
If someone reading this wants to incorporate the above in a document that uses `hyperref`, you should add an additional `{}` after `{<page>}`.

Comment: How would you adapt this solution to the OP's apparent objective of listing a bunch of unnumbered entries in the ToC?

Comment: @Mico: I should've considered that. By leaving out `\numberline{…}` is the answer.

Comment: @mico: see modified answer ↑↑.

Answer (score 6):

If you want make manually a ToC just as LaTeX does, it has been already answered, but the question is a duplicate of  [How to make Table of Contents manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457258/how-to-make-table-of-contents-manually).

If you want just the example as you posted, it could be using `tocloft` as Mico showed, or as simple as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Table of Contents} 
{\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Introduction \dotfill  1\par
Next Point   \dotfill 2\par}
\end{document}
```

The dotted line of `\dotfill` is more dense that those of a normal ToC, but you can construct your own dotted line. The below example is a macro with a more sparse dots (bonus: a "WYSIWYG" odd syntax).

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\toc#1...#2 {\noindent#1\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill#2\par}
\begin{document}
\section*{Table of Contents}
\toc Introduction...1
\toc Next Point...22
\toc Last Point...312
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Of course, if you prefer a more orthodox syntax (e.g. `\toc{Introduction}{1}`) simply define the macro with `\newcommand\toc[2]{...}` or `\def\toc#1#2{...}`.

Comment: Perhaps my solution is a little elaborate for the intended application, and I probably should have found that question…

Answer (score 5):

You asked,

> Is there a way to make a single page table of contents ... [w]ithout generating it [from] a LaTex-Document?

I assume that by "without generating it from a LaTeX document", you mean "without creating a LaTeX document prefaced by a `\tableofcontents` directive". Since you posted your query to this site, I'm also assuming that you are not actually averse to creating this table of contents via a `\documentclass ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}` structure, i.e., via a LaTeX document.

If these assumptions are correct, the following solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft} %% used only for '\cftsubsecleader' macro
\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\obeylines
\textbf{Table of Contents}
\smallskip
Introduction \cftsubsecleader 1
Next Point   \cftsubsecleader 2
\end{document}
```