# Colored font for the Chapters in a manually generated TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

The following code for generating TOC manually, is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457258/how-to-make-table-of-contents-manually):

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}
\contentsline {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}
\end{document}
```

I want to have colored fonts for Chapters. One of the way is to use the `\textcolor{blue}{Colored text}`. This is cumbersome if there numerous Chapters. Is there a way of setting the color for the entries of the Chapters, globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\usepackage{xcolor} % needed for the color commands
\usepackage{xpatch} % provides the command \xpatchcmd
\makeatletter % make @ a normal letter such that we can use \l@chapter as macro name
\xpatchcmd\l@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother % turn @ again into a non-letter
```

If you want to color also the page number on the right end of the line in blue, replace `\textcolor` by `\color` in the `\xpatchcmd` line above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\l@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}
\contentsline {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}
\end{document}
```

**Complete line in blue:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\l@chapter{#1}{\color{blue}#1}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentsline {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}
\contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}
\contentsline {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}
\contentsline {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect yet. The chapter numbers also changes its color.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\contentslinex}[3]{%    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{chapter}}
    {\contentsline{#1}{\color{red}#2}{\color{black}#3}}
    {\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
}


\begin{document}
\noindent{\bfseries{\huge Contents}\hfill Page No.\vspace \bigskipamount \par }
\contentslinex {chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ii}
\contentslinex {chapter}{ABSTRACT}{iii}
\contentslinex {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{iv}
\contentslinex {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{v}
\contentslinex {chapter}{ABBREVIATIONS}{vi}
\contentslinex {chapter}{NOTATIONS}{viii}
\contentslinex {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{1}
\contentslinex {section}{\numberline {1.1}General Background}{1}
\contentslinex {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objective}{3}
\contentslinex {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Objective 1}{5}
\contentslinex {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Objective 2}{12}
\contentslinex {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Objective 3}{15}
\contentslinex {section}{\numberline {1.3}Scheme}{16}
\end{document
```