# How to Modify a Latex Program to Display Only the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, printing

I am working on a LaTeX document that will likely result in a Table of Contents that spans a large number of pages. When the document is finished, I would like to ``carve-out'' the TOC from the document and treat it separately.

In the following MWE, I have the TOC (which runs across two unnumbered pages at the end of the document---pages 17 and 18 actually) appear at the end of the document.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 12pt} %set space after each 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries \dotfill}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Chapter 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter*{Chapter 4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 4}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{Chapter 5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 5}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Chapter 6}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 6}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Chapter 7}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 7}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter*{Chapter 8}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 8}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{Chapter 9}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 9}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Chapter 10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 10}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Chapter 11}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 11}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter*{Chapter 12}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 12}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{Chapter 13}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 13}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Chapter 14}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 14}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Chapter 15}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 15}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter*{Chapter 16}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 16}
\lipsum[4]

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I would now like to modify the above program so that when I run it---ONLY the TOC appears.

QUESTION: Is it possible to specify in a LaTeX program that I want only a specific range of pages (17-18 in this case) to appear? And if so, how may I accomplish that? I will then, on one hand, have a separated TOC; upon which, I can run the program a second time with `\tableofcontents` blotted out.

Thank you.

Comment: You can extract the toc like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457284/11604). See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection) to print specific pages only... but is not just easier cut the PDF with `pdftk` or some similar tool?

Comment: in the second run of latex use only `\begin{document}\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make a separate document for only the table of contents. In this way you don't have to change anything in the original document.

For example if your original report is `report1.tex`, create a file `report1toc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\input report1.toc
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Use the same documentclass as the original document. If your original file contains packages or commands that change the page size, the fonts or formatting of chapter headings (for the Contents heading), and/or the formatting of the table of contents, copy these also to the preamble of this file. Then after running the LaTeX on the original document, run it also on this new document, and it will only contain the toc (most probably with the same formatting as in your original document.